# Implement "Use system value" in custom module

Tags: magento2, configuration, system-config, core-config-data, default-values

In the magento backend under `Stores -> Configuration` some of the fields have the **"Use system value"** checkbox next to them and some don't have it.

[image]

Checking the checkbox "restores" the field to the default value (which is defined in module's `config.xml` file).

How can I implement this **"Use system value" checkbox** in a custom module? Is it possible?

When I add custom config fields to my module, they don't have this "Use system value" checkbox.

Answer (score 6):

**canRestore** property

etc/adminhtml/system.xml

```
<field id="some" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="30" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1" canRestore="1">
    ...
</field>
```